# Read RTF file content in asp.net with Aspose.Words

Tags: asp.net, rtf, aspose.words

I need to read a .RTF file with some text inside and then save it in a String variable, i searching a lot online and there is not free method to do it. 
I have a commercial license of Aspose.Words, its possibile to do with that library (or in every way)?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text representation of RTF document by using the following simple Aspose.Words code:

```
Document doc = new Document("E:\\temp\\in.rtf");
string rtfText = doc.ToString(SaveFormat.Text);
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.